# what is a partition class in Apache Giraph? eg -pc in Giraph job

Tags: graph, data-partitioning, giraph

What is partitionClass (-pc) in giraph job submitted through command line ?
What are the arguments or how to give the arguments ? Could u please give an example ? I saw the API which says Hash partitioning etc.. but couldnt find an example to see how to submit a job with -pc.